# jQuery click to load video/change thumbnail not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, vimeo

[bigideahelm](http://bigideahelm.com/)

I'm working on this Vimeo integration. I'm trying to swap out videos when you click on a particular thumbnail. Using a quick and dirty method of swapping classes with addClass and removeClass. Also swapping out the video with html function.

Trying to do this without reloading the page. It looks like the html updates but the videos do not update properly. Anyone have any thoughts?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <div class="jake"><img style="display:inline; position: relative;" src="wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/jake.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="katy"><img style="display:inline; position: relative;" src="wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/katy.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="cary"><img style="display:inline; position: relative;" src="wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/cary.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
```

And the jQuery code (I've only included one section of the code, it's repeated for each video thumbnail):

```
//CARY
jQuery(".cary").click(function(){
  jQuery('#videoplayer').html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57695418?api=1" width="470" height="264" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>');

  if(!(jQuery('div').hasClass('jake'))) {
    jQuery('.cary').html('<img style="display:inline; position: relative;" src="wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/jake.jpg" />');
    jQuery('.cary').addClass('jake');
    jQuery('.jake').removeClass('cary');
  }

  if(!(jQuery('div').hasClass('katy'))) {
    jQuery('.cary').html('<img style="display:inline; position: relative;" src="wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/katy.jpg" />');
    jQuery('.cary').addClass('katy');
    jQuery('.katy').removeClass('cary');
  }

  if(!(jQuery('div').hasClass('roderick'))) {
    jQuery('.cary').html('<img style="display:inline; position: relative;" src="wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/roderick.jpg" />');
    jQuery('.cary').addClass('roderick');
    jQuery('.roderick').removeClass('cary');
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean that the videos do not update properly?  You realize that `jQuery('div')` selects *all* divs, right?

Comment: The video currently showing does not have it's thumbnail displaying. I'm using .hasClass("ClassName") to search for which one is in the videoplayer window. It's a quick and dirty solution, but it works.

Take a look at the link and scroll down to the video player to see what I am referring to. Click on a few videos and you'll see the issue.

Comment: Instead of using `.hasClass` I think you want to use `$(this).hasClass`.  The `.hasClass` will return true all the time because *every* div is being checked and this will totally not work as you expect.

Comment: That seems to be working out because their is only one of that class on the page. Thanks for the help though but I've solved my issue. Using the on function seems to update the DOM according and everything seems to be working as intended now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the on function seems to update the DOM according and everything seems to be working as intended now. I was trying to change elements on the page as opposed to show/hiding elements that are already loaded.